# Team Explorer 2010 and 2012 for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I would like to be able to connect Team explorer (tfs) to both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 on my computer. Right now I have Visual Studio 2010 connected to Team Explorer 2010.

What can I do to make visual studio 2012 connect to team explorer 2010? Is there some kind of a compatibility addon I can download?

Is what I am asking possible? If not, can I have both team explorer 2010 (connecting to Visual studio 2010) and another team explorer 2012 (connecting to visual studio 2012)?

I could possible download a newer version of visual studio of that would help.

Would you tell me what you suggest?

Comment: Are you using the phrase "team explorer" interchangeably with "TFS"? You don't connect **to** Team Explorer. You use Team Explorer to connect to TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to connect Team explorer (tfs) to both Visual
>   Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 on my computer.

You should be able to do this use Visual Studio 2010(with Team Explorer 2010) and Visual Studio 2012(with Team Explorer 2012) directly. It's supported to use multiple visual studio with different version to connect TFS.

You don't have to make visual studio 2012 connect to team explorer 2010. And also just as Daniel mentioned: You don't connect to Team Explorer. You use Team Explorer to connect to TFS.

All you need pay attention to is the client compatibility for TFS and Visual Studio. For this part, please take a look at our official tutorial here-- [Visual Studio and Team Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops#visual-studio-and-team-explorer)

You could also refer jessehouwing's blog which got all options documented on it: [Connect any version of Visual Studio to Azure DevOps or Azure DevOps Server](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-connect-any-visual-studio-version/)

Comment: The following items to bring up: You mentioned 'You don't have to make visual studio 2012 connect to team explorer 2010. And also just as Daniel mentioned: You don't connect to Team Explorer. You use Team Explorer to connect to TFS.' Thus it sounds like team explorer is a standalone app that I use, correct? If not, what I am missing? How will I find the Team Explorer to use and connect to the visual studio 2012 files?

Comment: From your matrix and by looking at the internet, it looks like I need to download github from the following location: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jzoss.GitSourceControlProvider2015 . When I click on this link it says i need Visual studio 2012 update 2. However all the links for this are no longer available. Thus if I get the latest update to visual studio 2012, would this solve my issue

Comment: I tried to download from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jzoss.GitSourceControlProvider2015 and I got the message. The installation was unable to install the extension to all the selected products. For more information, click on the install log link at the bottom of the dialog. This extension is not installable on any current installed products.

Comment: @user1816979 What you shared link Easy Git Integration Tools which is a plug-in that integrates git with Visual Studio. However, it does not support Visual Studio 2012. As you can see in the right part of your shared link. There is a 
**Works with**, it only support Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019.  So you are not able to use both this extension and git in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: `Thus it sounds like team explorer is a standalone app that I use, correct? If not, what I am missing? How will I find the Team Explorer to use and connect to the visual studio 2012 files` Yes you could say this, we are able to add/install team explorer  separately. This is used for some specific cases.  After you installed Visual Studio, you should be able to see Team Explorer which is tabbed along with the solution explorer (At the bottom of the solution explorer window).If not, click view->Team Explorer (Ctrl+M). From there you should be able to connect to your TFS instance.

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question.